# PHP Empty query string variables $_GET

Tags: php, query-string

Do you see a problem with using the following convention for "views" (as in MVC).

```
webpage.php?past
script.php?all
page.php?about
```

For the PHP itself, I check for those values as such:

```
if(isset($_GET['past'])){
   ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

This works fine on all major browsers, so far.

Comment: Wrong how? It's perfectly acceptable as far as URLs go.

Comment: Weird question. No it's not a problem.

Comment: @Jules - Weird answer. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax is quite valid in terms of URL spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4

Just ensure that any special characters are encoded as you'd have to do in any URL anyway